# Why I can't create a table in my database in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm trying to create a new table in my database but it's not working. See the code below:

```
public static void creerJoueur(string nom)
{
        bool ok = true;
        string connexionString = @"DataSource=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Rubis.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

        using (SqlConnection connexion = new SqlConnection(connexionString))
        {
            connexion.Open();
            string query = "Create table " + nom +  " (noSemaine int primary key, montant int)";
            SqlCommand commande = new SqlCommand(query, connexion);

            try
            {
                ok = commande.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ok = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't see my error. In debug, my program don't go in my catch section, so there is no error. I just can't see my new table. `commande.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns -1. Please help me.

UPDATE: The code is fine but the table appeared several minutes after running my program. Any solution for this??

UPDATE 2: I created a new database named taxeRubis. In visual Studio, I dont see any table after executing my code. If I go in sql server, there is 2 database named taxeRubis not at the same location: gyazo.com/5c05765b9b8f4ee8312329edf01e157e One have my table named Bodhis, the other don't. Why I have now 2 databases?

Comment: Connect to `master` Db using connection string in `C#` and then query as `use[YouDb] CREATE TABLE etc.`

Comment: Why connect to master first?

Comment: Its owner of your Db and has rights for it. You cannot do it directly. But normally you can do all other operations except alteration using direct connection

Comment: It's weird, I always use my database directly. I will try but how to connect to master? It's not a local DB.

Comment: The `ExecuteNonQuery` return value is the **number of rows** affected, by an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement. Since you have none of that in your query, then of course no rows were affected, so the return value is `-1` - which is **not** an error! It just means, no rows were affected by an operation - which is fine since you're creating a table .. and [it **is** all nicely documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you'd just care to go look for it ...

Comment: Its similar just replace the name of database to `master`

Comment: @marc_s But I can't see my new table that I created.

Comment: @EmilePettersen-Coulombe r u able to run the query more than one time with same value in nom? it should give an error object already exist on second time if you use same value in nom. see my answer below. After executing the query just refresh your database and see the table will be there. I am able to create in my test env

Comment: Maybe you need to write out an exception, if one occurs, to find out what might be going wrong. The table could already exist or other things - but if you just "swallow" the exception and do nothing, you'll never know ....

Comment: @marc_s It's why I have a try catch

Comment: Yes you have - but you're not **doing** anything if an exception happens!! You need to check **what** exception occurs, and **what the message** tells you!! That might be the answer to why your table isn't created! Right now, you're **just ignoring** the exception case!

Comment: In debug, my program do not go in my catch section so there is no error

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the "(" in front of LocalDB. i.e.

```
connexionString = @"DataSource=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Rubis.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

Comment: There is a "(" in front of LocalDB no?

Comment: That is correct. It is needed there when using (LocalDB) as a DataSource.

Comment: Oh I see it hahaha but it's only a copy paste error

Comment: Do you get a compile error of: "cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool' on your `ok = commande.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1; ?

Comment: No I just did a mistake by asking my question on stackoverflow :) There is a "(" in my code before LocalDB

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked your database after executing the query. Have a look the table will be there. The `ExecuteNonQuery()` is  returning `-1` because it is not effecting any row. It is just creating a table. So your query is working.

> I tested the same in my test environment. I am getting -1 but the
>   table is getting created in database

```
    string nom = "test123";
    string query = "Create table " + nom + " (noSemaine int primary key, montant int)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    try
   {
     int ii = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     MessageBox.Show(ii.ToString());
    }
```

[image: value after executenonquery]

[image: table]

your syntax in connection string is wrong 
try below

```
connexionString = @"DataSource=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|
\Rubis.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

Also avoid string concatenation while providing user input. It can result in [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
you can make your sql query as below

```
db.Execute(string.Format("CREATE TABLE {0} (noSemaine int primary key, montant int)", nom));
```

Comment: It could be the problem? And how I put that SQL Injection in my code ?

Comment: @Emilepettersen-coulombe it is not the problem i said it can sometime result in sql injection..you can avoid sql injection by the way putting the query as specified here. Also while debugging what the value coming in the string variable nom?

Comment: nom contains a string that I take from a textbox from a wpf application. It's not the problem I think. I saw the good string with a spy.

Comment: @Émile Pettersen-Coulombe check your database the table will be there..i tested in my env it is working

Comment: My code worked before and for a reason, I have this problem that I can't see my new tables. I think I didnt change my code since this moment but I can't see my new tables. It could be a db bug? I'm trying to reinstall sql server 2014.

Comment: @EmilePettersen-Coulombe r u able to run the query more than two time with same value in nom?

Comment: @EmilePettersen-Coulombe r u able to run the query more than one time with same value in nom? it should give an error object already exist on second time if you use same value in nom. see my answer below. After executing the query just refresh your database and see the table will be there. I am able to create in my test env

Comment: Yes I'm able to run the query more than one time with the same value.This is so weird. And I can't see my tables like you.

Comment: ok if u r able to do that..then there is something weird but i dont think its pblm with sqlserver..can you tell me what value u used in nom?

Comment: I tried Bodhis a few times but nom (name in french) is only string that represent people. Each people in my app will have his table.

Comment: u r sure the value from textbox is coming to nom string variable right??

Comment: Yes. There is a possibility that my table will appear with a delay?

Comment: i don't think it is working fine in my system as shown in the answer

Comment: Ok I will try something. There is no error and you are able to create a table. So I will try to run my application and I will wait a few minutes if I do not see my table instantly.

Comment: Ok wow I found the problem. It takes 3 min. to the table to be created. Any solution for this?

Comment: oh 3 min..no idea..mine created at same time

Comment: I created a new database named taxeRubis. In visual Studio, I dont see any table after executing my code. If I go in sql server, there is 2 database named taxeRubis not at the same location:

http://gyazo.com/5c05765b9b8f4ee8312329edf01e157e

One have my table named Bodhis, the other don't. Why I have now 2 databases?

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is wrong.
Try:

Open your dataBase properties -> Copy Connection String from there and then pass it to to new SqlConnection(...);

Comment: If my connection string is wrong why I dont have error when connexion.Open() comes? I should try to use this? Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="D:\Utilisateurs\Emile\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CalculRubis2\CalculRubis2\Rubis.mdf";Integrated Security=True

Comment: ` string connexionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\umar chaudhry\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Rubis.mdf;Integrated Security=True"; `

I have used this code and its perfectly working for me, i think there is conflict in databases for both in prject folder and one in the bin problem

Comment: Try giving the path of db in bin folder, may be that should work
As sometimes visual studio starts reading from the database in the main folder and for write operations, it uses database in the bin folder

Comment: When I close visual studio, the database who isn't in bin dissapear from sql server. It's normal?